# Where does the actual cloud function unit test { firebase-functions-test } run when ran using a test framework?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know, where does the cloud function unit test run, when ran using a test runner (say **mocha** or **jest**)?

```
npm run test
```

***FYI, I am not running inside any of the firebase emulators***

When I run using **mocha**, it is able to create write to the **firestore** (I am sure **jest** will do the same), but I can't see the function names in the logs, **which means, the function ran locally inside test runner and wrote to firestore db.**

Does that mean the https callable cloud functions can't be called from firebase backend using test runner?
I have tried both ways: that is directly calling the functions and wrapping using wrap() method provided by firebase-functions-test library. both times the function ran locally.

**direct call:**

```
.....
.....
.....
funcName.run({foo:"bar"}, { auth: { uid: "ABC" } });
.....
.....
.....
```

**using wrap:**

```
.....
.....
.....
const projectConfig = {
  projectId: 'my-project',
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com'
};
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(projectConfig, './service-account-key.json');
wrapped = test.wrap(funcName);
expect(
        wrapped(
            { foo: "bar" },
            { auth: { uid: "ABC" } }
        )
).to.contain('foobar');
.....
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean the https callable cloud functions can't be called from firebase backend using test runner?

The firebase-functions-test framework is designed to run everything locally, so you get predictable and reliable execution without a dependency on some external network connection.  It will not run anything remotely.

If you want to run a callable function that's been deployed somewhere, you can write code to invoke it directly using any normal HTTP client library, and onCall protocol information provided in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).